# How can I find out what carrier an iPhone 3gs is locked to?

Tags: iphone, unlock

I'm trying to activate an old 3gs but am unsure of what carrier it is on. I don't really want to go testing all the sim cards I can find to see if I luck out.

Does anyone know of a way to find out?

I was wondering if I could write an app for it and use the `Core Telephony Framework` to find the carrier but am not sure if that only show the carrier that is being used by the sim not what it is locked to.

Comment: Can you read the model number from the back of the device?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [small app](http://www.copytrans.net/copytranscontacts.php) which can show you the carrier with which your iPhone is associated.

[image]

The app itself is not free but the sole function of displaying the iphone information you require is free.

Comment: This program indicates the network of the SIM card. Not the network the phone is locked to.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, the iPhone 3GS was only available for AT&T. Unless it is jailbroken, it will be AT&T.

Comment: The 3GS was not only sold in the US though...

Comment: Ah right. Good point.